# Is there an analog of TweenMax

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is there an alternative of Tweenmax for as3?

Or is it better for create animation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, TweenLite and TweenMax are the best tweening libraries out there. They've got some amazing features, and a very good plugins structure. 
You can tween properties and filters, build sequences, reverse tweening, manipulate easing, attach callbacks to onInit, onUpdate, onFinished, and lot of features more.
I've been using them for lot of years, and I'm so happy that I've bought the Greensock membership!

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of AS3 Tween engines: Tweener, gTween, Tweensy, eaze-tween... and don't forget the good old native fl.transitions.Tween !

Each engine has it's own specificity, Greensock tween engine (TweenMax) is just the most popular... it's very easy to use and like Sr.Richie said very powerful. They have a ASDoc, very good examples and a WYSIWYG tween editor.

If you want to test some alternatives, [here is a little comparison](http://blog.stroep.nl/2010/11/comparing-tween-engines/) between most used AS3 tween engines.

Answer (score 0):

In case you mean you want an alternative, there's also gtween: http://gskinner.com/libraries/gtween/

Answer (score 0):

Check [Tweensy](http://code.google.com/p/tweensy/) - it is working very well, is quite advanced and doesn't have licence limitations like TweenMax.